# Esp32: Dual Core task crashing even though same command works elsewhere

Tags: arduino, heap-corruption

I have ventured beyond my ability in this one.

This project is for an IoT demo to some students. Using Telegram they can control some lighting as well as receive some notifications to events.

The following are confirmed to be working:

All lighting and lighting telegram messages

Temperature sensor and telegram messages

Door bell but NOT the telegram message

If `bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Someone is at the door.", "");` is added to the soundDoorbell() function then the following crash occurs

```
CORRUPT HEAP: Bad head at 0x3fff479c. Expected 0xabba1234 got
0x3ffffff8 abort() was called at PC 0x40086cd1 on core 0

ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Backtrace: 0x40088904:0x3ffdc5d0 0x40088b81:0x3ffdc5f0
0x40086cd1:0x3ffdc610 0x40086dfd:0x3ffdc640 0x400f6bcf:0x3ffdc660
0x400f2ebd:0x3ffdc920 0x400f2e4c:0x3ffdc970 0x4008d25d:0x3ffdc9a0
0x40081f1e:0x3ffdc9c0 0x4008208d:0x3ffdc9e0 0x40123ca6:0x3ffdca00
0x4011706a:0x3ffdca20 0x400d3a28:0x3ffdca40 0x400d3629:0x3ffdca60
0x400d37fb:0x3ffdca80 0x400d38f1:0x3ffdcab0 0x400d464d:0x3ffdcad0
0x400d707d:0x3ffdcb00 0x400d15cd:0x3ffdcba0 0x400d16a3:0x3ffdcbc0
0x40089b92:0x3ffdcc00

Rebooting... ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x17 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT) configsip: 0,
SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1 load:0x3fff0018,len:4 load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:10124 load:0x40080400,len:5856 entry 0x400806a8
```

The decode stack shows:

```
0x40088904: invoke_abort at
/home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp32/panic.c
line 156 0x40088b81: abort at
/home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp32/panic.c
line 171 0x40086cd1: lock_acquire_generic at
/home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/newlib/locks.c
line 143 0x40086dfd: _lock_acquire_recursive at
/home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/newlib/locks.c
line 171 0x400f6bcf: _vfiprintf_r at
../../../.././newlib/libc/stdio/vfprintf.c line 860 0x400f2ebd:
fiprintf at ../../../.././newlib/libc/stdio/fiprintf.c line 50
0x400f2e4c: __assert_func at ../../../.././newlib/libc/stdlib/assert.c
line 59 0x4008d25d: multi_heap_free at
/home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/heap/multi_heap_poisoning.c
line 218 0x40081f1e: heap_caps_free at
/home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/heap/heap_caps.c line 268 0x4008208d: esp_mbedtls_mem_free at
/home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/port/esp_mem.c
line 35 0x40123ca6: mbedtls_free at
/home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/platform.c
line 98 0x4011706a: mbedtls_ssl_free at
/home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ssl_tls.c
line 8992 0x400d3a28: stop_ssl_socket(sslclient_context*, char const*,
char const*, char const*) at
C:\Users\abas034\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6\libraries\WiFiClientSecure\src\ssl_client.cpp
line 272 0x400d3629: WiFiClientSecure::stop() at
C:\Users\abas034\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6\libraries\WiFiClientSecure\src\WiFiClientSecure.cpp
line 93 0x400d37fb: WiFiClientSecure::connect(char const*, unsigned
short, char const*, char const*, char const*) at
C:\Users\abas034\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6\libraries\WiFiClientSecure\src\WiFiClientSecure.cpp
line 154 0x400d38f1: WiFiClientSecure::connect(char const*, unsigned
short) at
C:\Users\abas034\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6\libraries\WiFiClientSecure\src\WiFiClientSecure.cpp
line 112 0x400d464d: UniversalTelegramBot::sendGetToTelegram(String
const&) at C:\Users\abas034\UOA\OneDrive - The University of
Auckland\Documents\Arduino\libraries\UniversalTelegramBot\src\UniversalTelegramBot.cpp
line 73 0x400d707d: UniversalTelegramBot::getUpdates(long) at
C:\Users\ab\UOA\OneDrive - The University of
Auckland\Documents\Arduino\libraries\UniversalTelegramBot\src\UniversalTelegramBot.cpp
line 369 0x400d15cd: checkTelegramBot() at
C:\Users\ab\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\WorkingOn\IoT-Demo\HomeAutomationV3/HomeAutomationV3.ino
line 315 0x400d16a3: nonloopingCode(void*) at
C:\Users\ab\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\WorkingOn\IoT-Demo\HomeAutomationV3/HomeAutomationV3.ino
line 343 0x40089b92: vPortTaskWrapper at
/home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/freertos/port.c
line 143
```

Given that the "bot.sendMessage" function works everywhere else, I can't work out why it would fail in this instance.

Code

```
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    
    #ifdef ESP32
    #include 
    #else
    #include 
    #endif
    #include 
    #include    
    #include 
    
    #include "DHTesp.h"
    
    //Wifi & Telgram credentials
    #include "config.h"
    
    // Sensors & Control
    
    #define pin_DHT11 4 //
    #define pin_alarmsensor 2 //RCWL-0516
    #define pin_siren 19
    #define pin_led_veranda 26
    #define pin_led_bedroom 25
    #define pin_doorbell 27
    
    DHTesp dht;
    
    #define DATA_PIN    18
    #define LED_TYPE    WS2812 
    #define COLOR_ORDER GRB
    #define NUM_LEDS   12
    CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
    
    #define BRIGHTNESS          50
    #define FRAMES_PER_SECOND  120
    
    bool alarmArmed = false;
    bool alarmTriggered = false;
    bool partyledson = false;
    bool livingroomledson = false;
    
    int buttonState;             
    int lastButtonState = LOW;   
    unsigned long lastDebounceTime = 0;  
    unsigned long debounceDelay = 50;    
    
    WiFiClientSecure client;
    UniversalTelegramBot bot(BOTtoken, client);
    
    int botRequestDelay = 50;
    unsigned long lastTimeBotRan;
    
    char textoption;
    
    String chat_id;
    
    TaskHandle_t loopingTasks;
    TaskHandle_t nonloopingTasks;
    
    
    void GetTemperature() { //implemented
      String message = "Temperature: ";
      TempAndHumidity newValues = dht.getTempAndHumidity();
      message.concat(String(newValues.temperature)); message.concat(".");
      bot.sendMessage(chat_id, message, "");
    }
    
    void ToggleAlarm() {
      alarmArmed = !alarmArmed;
    
      if (alarmArmed) {
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Alarm armed.", "");
      }
      else bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Alarm disarmed.", "");
    
    }
    
    void TogglePartylights() {
      partyledson = !partyledson;
      if (partyledson) {
        livingroomledson = false;
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Party lights switched on.", "");
      }
      else bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Party lights switched off.", "");
    }
    
    void ToggleVerandaLights() {
      bool LightStatus = digitalRead(pin_led_veranda);
      LightStatus = !LightStatus;
      digitalWrite(pin_led_veranda, LightStatus);
      LightStatus = digitalRead(pin_led_veranda);
      if (LightStatus) {
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Veranda light switched on.", "");
      }
      else bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Veranda light switched off.", "");
    }
    
    void ToggleLivingRoomLights() {
      partyledson = false;
      bool LightStatus = livingroomledson;
      livingroomledson = !livingroomledson;
      if (livingroomledson) {
        for ( int i = 0; i (leds, NUM_LEDS).setCorrection(TypicalLEDStrip);
      FastLED.setBrightness(BRIGHTNESS);
      FastLED.clear();
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("Started");
    
      pinMode(pin_siren, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(pin_led_veranda, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(pin_led_bedroom, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(pin_alarmsensor, INPUT);
      pinMode(pin_doorbell, INPUT_PULLUP);
    
      // Connect to Wi-Fi
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
      WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
      client.setCACert(TELEGRAM_CERTIFICATE_ROOT);
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
      }
      // Print ESP32 Local IP Address
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    
      Serial.println("Bot started?");
      bot.sendMessage(CHAT_ID, "System restarted", "");
    
      //create a task that will be executed in the Task1code() function, with priority 1 and executed on core 0
      xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
        nonloopingCode,   /* Task function. */
        "nonloopingTasks",     /* name of task. */
        16384,       /* Stack size of task */
        NULL,        /* parameter of the task */
        1,           /* priority of the task */
        &nonloopingTasks,      /* Task handle to keep track of created task */
        0);          /* pin task to core 0 */
      delay(500);
    
      xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
        juggle,   /* Task function. */
        "loopingTasks",     /* name of task. */
        16384,       /* Stack size of task */
        NULL,        /* parameter of the task */
        1,           /* priority of the task */
        &loopingTasks,      /* Task handle to keep track of created task */
        1);          /* pin task to core 1 */
      delay(500);
    
    }
    
    void checkTelegramBot() {
      if (millis() > lastTimeBotRan + botRequestDelay) {
        int numNewMessages = bot.getUpdates(bot.last_message_received + 1);
    
        while (numNewMessages) {
          Serial.println("Got response");
          handleNewMessages(numNewMessages);
          numNewMessages = bot.getUpdates(bot.last_message_received + 1);
        }
        lastTimeBotRan = millis();
      }
    }
    
    void nonloopingCode(void * pvParamters) {
      Serial.print("nonloopingCode running on core ");
      Serial.println(xPortGetCoreID());
      for (;;) {
    
        if ((!partyledson) && (!livingroomledson)) {
          FastLED.clear();
          FastLED.show();
        }
        if (alarmArmed) {
          if (digitalRead(pin_alarmsensor)) {
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Alarm triggered", "");
            partyledson = false;
            alarmTriggered = true;
          }
        }
    
        checkTelegramBot();
      }
    }
    void juggle(void * pvParamters) {
      Serial.print("Juggle running on core ");
      Serial.println(xPortGetCoreID());
      for (;;) {
        checkDoorbell();
        if (alarmTriggered)soundAlarm();
        if (partyledson) {
          fadeToBlackBy( leds, NUM_LEDS, 20);
          byte dothue = 0;
          int i = 0;
          while ((i  debounceDelay) {
       if (reading != buttonState) {
          buttonState = reading;
          if (buttonState == LOW) {
            soundDoorbell();
          }
        }
      }
      lastButtonState = reading;
    }
    
    void loop() {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Telegram routines are threadsafe.

Using FreeRTOS mutexes (https://microcontrollerslab.com/arduino-freertos-mutex-tutorial-priority-inversion-priority-inheritance/), I managed to get it to work although there is lots of lag but that is an easier issue to sort out :)

Answer (score 0):

We once experienced this; in a bid to resolve this, we tried to reproduce the error and found out three major things could cause this issue:

1. if you don't introduce an infinite loop within the method attached to each core wherein you do all your operations. e.g

```
void juggle(void * pvParamters) {
      
      for (;;) {
      Serial.print("Juggle running on core ");
      Serial.println(xPortGetCoreID());
        checkDoorbell();
        if (alarmTriggered)soundAlarm();
        if (partyledson) {
          fadeToBlackBy( leds, NUM_LEDS, 20);
          byte dothue = 0;
          int i = 0;
          while ((i  debounceDelay) {
       if (reading != buttonState) {
          buttonState = reading;
          if (buttonState == LOW) {
            soundDoorbell();
          }
        }
        lastButtonState = reading;
      }
      
    }
```

2. If you don't introduce a delay mechanism in each loop using delay(n) or vTaskDelay(n) to enable some book keeping to be done by the Task's watchdog.
3. Also task priority and also cause this too. you can set both task to highest priority aswell.

Try approaching a fix in this direction, hope it works for you too.